# Conditional use of Zend queries .. how to construct?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have this select statement:

```
  $select = $someMapper->getDbTable()
            ->select()
            ->where('someid = ?', $id)
            ->order(array($sort.' '.$order));
```

Yet, what I want to do is only search for campid IF $id is present. I am currently repeating the query without the where which I find counter productive. Was hoping there would be a more abstract way of doing this.

Am I limited to constructing the sql myself?

Thanks!

EDIT: My new query..

```
$select = $hitsMapper->getDbTable()
          ->select()
          ->where('campid = ? or 0 = ?', $id, $id)
          ->where('? LIKE ? or 0 = ?', $searchRow, $search, $search)
          ->order(array($sort.' '.$order));
```

The first where works fine, but the second doesn't. $searchRow and $search are defaulted to 'ID' and '0' respectively.

Comment: Thanks for editing the tag Gordon, changing it to Zend-framework. I notice you have experience in Zend-framework and were inclined enough to change tag. So can you understand my confusion in that you didn't bother to try to answer my quetion? I can't help but think maybe you would be more useful answering questions than editing small tag mistakes like zend>>zend-framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $select = $someMapper->getDbTable()
            ->select()
            ->where('someid = ? or 0 = ?', $id, $id)
            ->order(array($sort.' '.$order));
```

If `id == 0` then you will be get all results, i think you want this. I dont sure about my implementation syntax in zend then if this fail you can fell free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thank! Do you know how I would do similar for a LIKE statement? I've amended my post. Have tried but getting empty prepare query error when no data supplied